# How separated can $28$ points in a cube with side-length $3$ be?

Tags: geometry

*Definition*: A set of points $S\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ is said to be $\delta$-separated if for every $p,q\in S$, one has $d(p,q)>\delta$, where $d()$ is the usual Euclidean metric.

It is easy to see that among any $28$ points lying in the cube $[0,3]\times[0,3]\times[0,3]$, there are at least two whose distance does not exceed $\sqrt{3}$. Indeed, splitting the cube into $27$ cubes of side-length $1$ each, as in the Rubik's cube, one of the little cubes must contain at least two points, and since the diameter of each little cube is $\sqrt{3}$, the result follows. Thus, any set of $28$ points in a cube with side-length $3$ is not $\sqrt{3}$ separated.

I am wondering whether the $\sqrt{3}$ can be improved. As an example, consider the
set
$$S=\{(x,y,z): x,y,z\in\{0,\frac{3}{2},3\}$$
The set $S$ has $27$ points, and these points form vertices of $8$ cubes, each of side-length $\frac{3}{2}$, which fill up the cube of side-length $3$. Some of them are shown in the image below.

[image]

If we add any point  to the set $S$, it must lie in one of these $8$ cubes. Now, if you put a point inside a cube of side-length $\frac{3}{2}$, there must be one vertex of the cube whose distance to that point is not larger than half the diameter of the cube. (Proof: Exercise), and that diameter is $\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}$. This raises the following question

**Question**: Is it true that any set of $28$ points in a cube with side-length $3$ is not $\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{4}$ separated? That is, is it true that among any set of $28$ points in a cube of side-length $3$, there are (at least) two points whose distance is at most $\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{4}$?

[image: Rubik's cube]

Comment: Check "Dense Packings of Equal Spheres in a Cube"

Comment: This is closely related to the problem of packing spheres in a cube,  although an adjustment has to be made for points (centers of spheres) near the cube's sides.

Comment: Thanks......................